# Error can not allocate 591.3 MB in R: How to resolve using ff package?

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection, portfolio

I am trying to generate Random Portfolio, but getting below error.

## Start with the names of the assets

```
port <- portfolio.spec(assets = c("^NSEI","ITC.NS", "SBIN.NS", "COALINDIA.NS", "ICICIBANK.NS", "TATAMOTORS.NS", "ADANIPORTS.NS", "UPL.NS", "LICHSGFIN.NS", "NTPC.NS", "ONGC.NS", "TCS.NS", "INFY.NS", "INFRATEL.NS", "DABUR.NS", "BHARTIARTL.NS", "GAIL.NS", "VEDL.NS", "MOTHERSUMI.NS", "WELSPUNIND.NS", "WIPRO.NS", "TATAPOWER.NS", "IDEA.NS", "CAIRN.NS", "UNITECH.NS"))
```

## Box

```
port <- add.constraint(port, type = "box", min = 0.05, max = 0.8)
```

## Leverage

```
port <- add.constraint(portfolio = port, type = "full_investment")
```

## Target Return

```
port <- add.constraint(portfolio = port, type="return", return_target=0.015)
```

## Generate random portfolios

```
rportfolios <- random_portfolios(port, permutations = 3100000, rp_method = "sample")
```

There are total 24 securities in my Portfolio and I am using Adjusted closing price for past 1 yr. I have done some trial and error method and come to know there is some issue with Permutations number, As I increase the number it increases the Vector MB like I put

```
Permuations = 4100000
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 782.0 Mb

Similarly if I decrease the

```
Permutations = 2100000
```

> Error in rp_transform(w = tportfolio, min_sum = min_sum, max_sum =
> max_sum,  :Infeasible portfolio created, perhaps increase
> max_permutations and/or adjust your parameters.

Comment: After lots of research I come across ff package in R. Can some please help to how i can resolve above issue using ff package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes here searching for answer to this problem.

Initially the main error

> Error in rp_transform(w = tportfolio, min_sum = min_sum, max_sum =
>   max_sum, :Infeasible portfolio created, perhaps increase
>   max_permutations and/or adjust your parameters.

is due to generation of insufficient number of feasible portfolios weights.

In the  [source code](https://github.com/R-Finance/PortfolioAnalytics/blob/master/R/constraint_fn_map.R), the function **rp_tranform** tries to transform a vector of infeasible portfolio weights to feasible one and on failure throws this error. From the source code

> # checks for infeasible portfolio
>     # Stop execution and return an
>   error if an infeasible portfolio is created
>    # This will be useful in
>   fn_map so that we can catch the error and take
>    # action (try again
>   with more permutations, relax constraints, different
>    # method to normalize, etc.)

So, you can relax your box constraints to

```
port <- add.constraint(port, type = "box", min = 0.01, max = 0.95)
```

or try changing some other constraints.